# Selecting a xml Node from and adding more nodes based on its value using xslt and c#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have a problem in writing an xslt as im a beginner to xslt.  The scenario is as below :
         From the Property with attribute name "Value" , i should check if it contains '^' symbol. If it contains, i should add more Property tags, for each of the value split by '^'.
         I tried doing it in xslt , but went nuts on the output which i got. 
    
     //logic
    
        Tried this, but could'nt figure out what logic needs to go inside the xsl foreach to add new property tags.

Please include any xslt resources where i can learn it.

Can i do the c# xml stuff's like

```
Function()
{
var splitstring[]=string.Split('^'); 
XmlAttribute.SetAttribute('Val1','splitstring[0]');
XmlAttribute.SetValue('Val2',splitstring[1]);
}
```

**Input xml :**

```
<Observation>
<Property Name="Type" Value="1234"/>
<Property Name="Code" Value="CodeA"/>
<Property Name="Value1" Value="12345^Val1^6789"/>
<Property Name="Unit" Value=""/>
<Property Name="Status" Value=""/>
</Observation>
```

This is the input xml

**Output xml :**

```
<Observation>
<Property Name="Type" Value="1234"/>
<Property Name="Code" Value="CodeA"/>
<Property Name="Value1" Value="12345"/>
<Property Name="Value2" Value="Val1"/>
<Property Name="Value3" Value="6789"/>
<Property Name="Unit" Value=""/>
<Property Name="Status" Value=""/>
</Observation>
 How can i integrate a c# code (because it's easy) or an xslt logic to make this happen?
```

Comment: The other answers which i looked did not have the attributes for the tags.. i need the output xml with all the attributes as well. XSLT  code will help me out.

Comment: I did the modification in xslt and got the output as well. I used 3 xsl:variables and then constructing Property node with the required Name attribute and value from the xsl variable. It worked. Will post the answer after reaching 15 reps.

Answer (score 0):

Try Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication137
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> properties = doc.Descendants("Property").ToList();
            for (int i = properties.Count - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            {
                XElement property = properties[i];
                string value = (string)property.Attribute("Value");
                if (value.Contains("^"))
                {
                    property.ReplaceWith(ReplaceElement(property));
                }
            }
        }
        static List<XElement> ReplaceElement(XElement element)
        {
            List<XElement> elements = new List<XElement>();
            string name = (string)element.Attribute("Name");
            string baseName = Regex.Match(name, @"[^\d]+").Value;
            string value = (string)element.Attribute("Value");
            string[] splitValues = value.Split(new char[] { '^' }).ToArray();
            for (int i = 1; i <= splitValues.Length; i++)
            {
                elements.Add(new XElement("Property", new XAttribute[] { 
                    new XAttribute("Name", baseName + i.ToString()),
                    new XAttribute("Value", splitValues[i - 1])
                }));
            }
            return elements;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, but how can i integrate within the xslt file

Comment: Why use xslt instead of the standard Net Libraries?

Comment: i have a parser which has to send data and not interpret with the data.  I need to only modify the xml, hence the xslt stuff came into picture

Comment: That is a contradiction to say "modify" without "interpret" (parse) with XML.  With XML you need to parse the tags names before modifying.  I know what you are trying to say that you do not need to interpret the innertext.  But this case you need to get find the "^" in the innertext.

Comment: I need to find '^' and then modify the xml structure through xslt therefore not bothering the code and keeping things configurable at a later stage.

Comment: Why xlst?  Your posting said c#.

Comment: I mean to ask if i can write the c# functions inside the xslt file itself.

Comment: See : https://docs.c1.orckestra.com/Functions/XSLT/XSLTFAQ?q=Fetching+data+in+XSLTs+using+inline+CSharp

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. That site was very much helpful.